# solve the exercise in an alternative way

Tags: group-theory

I have this exercise:

Assume that G and H are finite groups and that $|G|$ and $|H|$ are relatively prime. Show that the only group-homomorphism $\phi: G \rightarrow H$ is the trivial one.

**I want to solve this exercise without looking at the order of elements, only looking at the order of groups, images, kernels etc.** Is it possible to solve the exercise this way? I solved it looking at elements, assuming $\phi(a)\ne e'$, and a has order r. Then $\phi(a^r)=e'=\phi(a)^r$. Now the order of $\phi(a)$ must then be strictly less than r, since the groups are relatively prime and the order of an element divides the order of the group. But if we assume that the order of $\phi(a)$ is k, then $\phi(a)^r=\phi(a)^k$, and the division algorithm either gives that the order of $\phi(a)$ is less than k, or that r is a multiple of k, both a contradiction.

**But how do I solve it not looking at the order of an element? I heard it could be solved this way?,looking at order of images, groups, kernels etc**

I know that the order of the image of G $|\phi(G)|$ must divide the order of H. but I need to show that this order must be 1, and hence we only get the identity element. Any tips?(without using order of elements). I also know that since the Kernel is a subgroup, then the Kernel must divide the order of G, I don't know if this helps? If $|\phi(G)|$ divides $|G|$ I will be done, but is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have first isormophism theorem then you have $|G|=|ker\phi||im\phi|$. Noting that $|im\phi|$ divides $|H|$ you obtain what you want.